# Jenkins agent on Windows dropping connection

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins agent running on Windows 2019 server machine. It connects to master for awhile but after few seconds connections drops with this log message:

```
Apr 16, 2019 10:28:54 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: xyz

Apr 16, 2019 10:28:54 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Apr 16, 2019 10:28:58 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

I start agent with this command:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http:/jenkins.url/computer/AzureWin1/slave-agent.jnlp -secret here_is_secret
```

I am not sure what I can check or where to see exactly why agent drops it's connection.

UPDATE:
I have fixed port for JNLP and I can telnet to it from slave machine

Comment: can you please confirm if "TCP port for JNLP agents" is enabled?

Comment: Yes I have fixed port in jenkins configuration and I can telnet to that port from machine running slave